# Remove Strings From Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make an array of objects from the browsing history that can become links in a React list.

What this does is takes the `history` element and pushes it to the `user` object, then I take the name and ID, and `splice` it back into the array. I then filter it down to distinct values.

What I am left with, is an array that looks like this:

```js
[{id1,name1},{id2,name2},{id3,name3},"id1","id2","id3"]
```

which is almost exactly what I want, except if I'm going to map that to create links, I need to get rid of the `string` values.

It occurred to me to try skipping the `history` element and just make an array of matches, and any number of other things.
 `pop` and `shift` don't work to isolate the first object because then the whole function continually returns a single item.

This is the only way I have gotten a result close to what I want, I just need a simple way of filtering out `string` values from an array after it's created, or maybe before it's mapped out.

```js
    const getLead = async _id => {

    const res = await axios.get(`/api/leads/${_id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_LEAD,
      payload: res.data
    });  

      const { name } = res.data

      const match = { name, _id }

     const setPrevious = () => {
        const prevLeads = user.prevLeads
        const history = createBrowserHistory(getLead);  
        const prevLead = history.location.pathname.slice(6);

        prevLeads.push(prevLead);

        return prevLeads; 

      }

       const prevLeads = setPrevious(); 

       const [...spliceLeads] = prevLeads.splice(0,1,match,match);

       const distinct =  (value, index, self) => {
         return self.indexOf(value) === index;
       }

       const recentLeads =  prevLeads.filter(distinct) ;

      console.log(spliceLeads)

    }
```

Comment: Use `typeof your_string == 'string'`?: `prevLeads.filter(e => typeof e != 'string')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just check the `type` in your `.filter` logic:

```js
const array = [
  { test: 'ing' },
  1,
  new Date(),
  'this should be removed'
];

const result = array.filter(e => typeof e !== 'string');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution what has been provided already works like charm, that should be used for your solution, below I'm providing a bit different way to figure out if the element is a `string` or not.

I guess [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a good way to test each elements on an array and return only the passing once as a result. If you call on each item `Object.prototype.toString.call(e)` then it will return as a text if you have `[object String]` or something else. This can be also used to filter out your `string` values from your array.

See the example below:

```js
const prevLeads = [{id:'id1',name: 'name1'},{id: 'id2',name:'name2'},{id:'id3',name:'name3'},"id1","id2","id3"];

const filter = e => Object.prototype.toString.call(e) !== '[object String]';
const recentLeads = prevLeads.filter(filter);       

console.log(recentLeads);
```

I hope that helps!